# Select a drop down box using a WebElement (selenium)?

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu

I normally use this 
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("title"))).selectByVisibleText("Mr");
and this works perfectly fine.

I am moving a more PageFactory approach
I define the WebElement

@FindBy(id="title")
private WebElement title;

How do i select the option in the dropdown box using this ?

I try using this
driver.findElement((By) title )
but this does not give me the option of selectByVisibleText.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do what you were doing before.  The @FindBy notation just replaces the need for the driver.findElement command.  To use the select you need to do:

```
new Select(title).selectByVisibleText("Mr");
```